# Why I can not get the correct value of my <select> field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, javascript-framework, jquery-events

In my **index.html**, I have a selection drop down menu:

```
<select id="car">
    <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
    <option value="toyota">TOYOTA</option>
</select>
```

**My js:**

```
var c = $('#car');

var selection;

c.change(function(){

    if(c.val()==='bmw'){

        selection = 'BMW';

    }else if(c.val()==='toyota'){

        selection = 'TOYOTA';

    }

});

console.log(c.val());
console.log(selection);
```

When page firstly loaded, the initial selection is **BMW**, and I got console output "**BMW**" which is fine, then I select "**TOYOTA**", but the two console outputs are still "**BMW**".

How to get the current
 value of the selection outside jQuery `.change(...)` function after the selection has been changed??

**________________typo have been fixed____________**

`car.val()` and `Selection` are both my **typo** here in the post, in my code I do use `selection`, and `c.val()`.

My point is how to get the current selection value out side jQuery `change()` function. Please **do not** discuss on my **typo** any more. Thank you.

Comment: Where does the car variable that you're using inside c.change(...) come from? I can't see it declared anywhere in the code you posted. Alo, you're declaring a variable Selection, but then using selection later on - javascript is, as far as I'm aware, case-sensitive.

Comment: First thing I saw: `var Selection;` should be `var selection;` That may actually be your problem. Other thing: is console.log even called again?

Comment: You should be using `c.val()`, not `car.val()`.  The variable `car` doesn't exist.

Comment: Hi, car.val() is my typo, I do use c.val() in my code. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define your var selection with lowercase, as this:

```
var selection;
```

Why? Javascript is case sensitive, so, Sensitive and sensitive are distinct variables.

Also, you should define your car var, like this:

```
var selection;
c.change(function(){
    var car = $(this); //declare it
    if(car.val()==='bmw'){
        selection = 'BMW';
    }else if(car.val()==='toyota'){
        selection = 'TOYOTA';
    }
});
```

Comment: Please check my updated post. Both "Selection" and "car.val()" are my typo. In my real code I do use "selection" and "c.val()"

Answer (score 5):

You're looking at `car` when you should be using `c`. `car` does not have a `val()` method.

```
if(c.val()==='bmw'){

    selection = 'BMW';

} else if(c.val()==='toyota'){

    selection = 'TOYOTA';
}
```

Also note that `var Selection;` will not be the same variable as `selection` (lowercase).

---

A better approach might be:

```
c.change(function(){
    selection = c.find(":selected").text();
});
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/XespU/

Comment: "selection" is my typo, so does the "car.val()". I do use "selection" and "c.val()". My point is how to get updated value outside .change() function. Your example does not answer my question... because you alert(selection) inside jQuery change() function.

Comment: `selection` will be set to (outside of the scope of this event) with the current selected value of `#car` once the `change` event fires.